# Python. Fail to build tree base on the result of depth first search(with height of each node given). Not sure what's the problem when backtracking

Tags: python, tree, depth-first-search

The data input is a list with the hierarchy.

```
[node0 : 0(height), node1: 1 , node2: 2, node3:2, node4:1, node5: 2]
```

The tree I want then would be like

```
     node0
     /     \ 
   node1   node4
  /    \        \
 node2  node3  node5
```

Kinds of like turning the result of depth first search with height back to the tree

My code here is

```
def buildFirst(root, before):
if data.__len__ == 0:
    return
toinsert = data[0]

if toinsert.height <= root.height:
    return

while toinsert.height == root.height + 1:
    root.addchildren(toinsert)
    before = toinsert
    data.pop(0)
    toinsert = data[0]

if toinsert.height > root.height + 1:
    before.addchildren(toinsert)
    data.pop(0)
    buildFirst(before, toinsert)
```

main function:

```
root = data[0]
 data.pop(0)
 buildFirst(root, root)
```

Node4 and Node5 are missing.

Comment: please can you share [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20minimal%20working,to%20be%20demonstrated%20and%20reproduced.&text=A%20minimal%20working%20example%20may,short%20self-contained%20correct%20example.)